# Visual Studio not building correctly

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-2013

I've been having two different problems when trying to compile a C++ project today.

Sometimes it won't reflect any of my changes in the new build: If I change some wording on the output or change around actual functionality and compile and hit Start Debugging, it will behave exactly as it did before I made the changes.  Hitting Clean or Rebuild Solution fixes this, but it takes about a full minute to compile this.  I guess it's not detecting any changes, but in the output window I see it list the file names of files I made changes to...

I'm also getting a lot of "...already defined in main.obj" errors (one for every function and variable) whenever I try to use a header file or define a function outside of a class.  Renaming the functions lets it compile once, but then the second compile will bring up the errors again.  It kinda works if I just define the class in a .cpp file, don't use a header file, and don't use any functions outside of the class.

The project is an open-source program I downloaded the other day to mess with (I'm building a bot to control it).  I didn't have the first problem until today, but the second one's always been happening.  All I've done is add a file (two if you count both Bot.cpp and Bot.h); Bot.cpp includes Bot.h and some files from the program, and the program's main.cpp includes Bot.cpp.

I'll post some code I guess, but I can't find anything wrong with what I'm doing.  I'm wondering if there's something I need to do to the existing files? (there were VS solution files included with the project that I used to open it, since VS Express doesn't help you create projects from existing code.)

```
//Bot.h
#ifndef _Bot_h_
#define _Bot_h_ 1

#include <string>

class Bot{
private:
    uint32 inputs = 0;
    bool active = false;

public:

    Bot(){};
    ~Bot(){};

void Start();
void Stop();
void Run();

void Wait(int seconds);
void Press(int buttons);
};

#endif


//Bot.cpp
#ifndef _Bot_cpp_
#define _Bot_cpp_ 1

#include "main.h"
//Some other project files included between these
#include "Bot.h"

using namespace std;

void Bot::Start(){
    if (active == false){
        active = true; 
        Run();
    }
}
void Bot::Stop(){
    active = false;
}
void Bot::Run(){
    while (active == true){
        printf("Has my code updated?\n");
        Wait(2);
    }
}

//There are more functions defined here

#endif
```

All I've really done in the original source code is include Bot.cpp at the bottom of the list of includes in the main.cpp file, and then add a call to create the class.  I'm a little out of practice with C/C++ so maybe it's something simple.  I'm also bad at writing posts like this so if anything needs clarified I'll try to help.

Comment: it's the compiler telling you to go to bed.

Comment: "these are not the files you're looking for"

Comment: I've had Visual Studio issue cryptic (and incorrect) build errors because the precompiled headers get out of sync. The IDE does not always detect when a dependency in `stdafx.h` has changed. Recompiling `stdafx.cpp` usually fixes it for me.